# What is the (e) in a function or for loop?

Tags: javascript

I've just finished a course at CodeCademy & I started to look into JavaScript in the wild. I ran into this (e) business I've never seen before.

```
var ge = function(e) {
    return document.getElementById(e)
},
gc = function(e) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(e)
}
```

What does this do exactly? I get that it gets the ID & ClassName of HTML elements, but what HTML elements?

Comment: It's just the name of the variable used as a parameter for the function, generally we use `e` to mean `event` or `element`.

Comment: if you want to know what e is, print it to the console in the first line of the function where e is the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

in these:

```
var ge = function(e) {
    return document.getElementById(e)
},
gc = function(e) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(e)
}
```

`e` is nothing more than the parameter being passed into the functions.  They actually having nothing in common except that they are named the same.  In the first one, e is supposed to be the value of the attribute `id` of the element you are looking for.   In the second, it's supposed to be the class name.

Although not necessary, I would have written the functions like this to be a little more clear (I would have changed the function names too, but to show the correlation between the examples, I left them the same):

```
function geId (idValue) {
    return document.getElementById(idValue)
},
function gc (className) {
    return document.getElementsByClassName(className)
}
```

Comment: You mean passed into the *functions* not *objects* ? :)

Comment: oops, good catch.  I mean functions are objects, so technically I'm still correct, but yeah that's what I meant :)